# How to return an array from javascript? (ExecuteScript)

Tags: c#, .net, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Although returning a string is cake, I just can't figure out how to return an array, this is an example that does not work (myURLs is a global array variable):

```
       List<object> list = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
        "window.myURLs = ['aa']; window.myURLs.push('bb'); return window.myURLs" 
        ) as List<object>;
```

The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If anyone has an example of returning an array I would love to see it!

Comment: "object" should be written as "Object"

Comment: @Mik378 `object` is an alias for `System.Object` in C#, so that makes no difference.

Comment: If you let it return that array as a string, what would it contain? For example, does it give you the string `"['aa','bb']"` or something else, or nothing at all?

Comment: I read too quickly, I though that it was a Java code ;)

Comment: @Mik378 Yep, drives me nuts when I try to write java, and it yells at me when I type `string`.

Comment: If I return it as a string I get:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When returning an array from JavaScript, the .NET bindings return a `ReadOnlyCollection<object>`, not a `List<object>`. The reason for this is that you cannot expect to change the contents of the returned collection and have them updated in the JavaScript on the page. The following is [an example](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dotnet/test/WebDriver.Common.Tests/ExecutingJavascriptTest.cs) taken from the WebDriver project's own .NET [integration tests](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dotnet/test/WebDriver.Common.Tests/).

```
List<object> expectedResult = new List<object>();
expectedResult.Add("zero");
expectedResult.Add("one");
expectedResult.Add("two");
object result = ExecuteScript("return ['zero', 'one', 'two'];");
Assert.IsTrue(result is ReadOnlyCollection<object>, "result was: " + result + " (" + result.GetType().Name + ")");
ReadOnlyCollection<object> list = (ReadOnlyCollection<object>)result;
Assert.IsTrue(CompareLists(expectedResult.AsReadOnly(), list));
```

Comment: Works a treat. Nice to get a lightning reply from a Selenium author, that's what Stack is all about :D